# Google Maps Loaded in a hidden DIV - problem with checkResize();

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am loading a google map in a hidden DIV. If I click a span, the DIV shows up.
This is my map Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("maps", "2.x");
function initialize() {
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_sm"));
  var location = new GLatLng(50.72251, 10.44476);
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(50.72251, 10.44476), 13);
  map.setUIToDefault();
  map.enableRotation();
  map.disableScrollWheelZoom();
  var marker = new GMarker(location);
  map.addOverlay(marker);
  map.checkResize();
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize); 
</script>
```

And this is my js function to show the map:

```
<script>    
jQuery('#sm_map').click(function() {
        jQuery('body').css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','':'hidden'});
        jQuery('#overlay_sm').fadeIn();

    });

    jQuery('.overlay_close').click(function() {
               jQuery('.map_overlay').fadeOut();                                        
    });
</script>
```

Where do I have to add the checkResize() ? I tried it on many places but did not suceed.

Many Thanks in advance
Theresa

Comment: chances are that if the div is hidden to begin with, it doesn't have the proper size attrs applied to it. What i would do to 'correct' this, is to create the div Offscreen to the left ( like at left:-10000). Do the GMaps2 function stuff.. then set the div to be hidden. Place it where it is suppose to be and THEN do the fadeIn and fadeOut

Answer (score 0):

`checkResize` doesn't actually check for a resize - it notifies the map that a resize has occurred. You need to check for the resize yourself:

```
$(document).resize(function(){
    map.checkResize();
});
```

You know GMaps V2 is deprecated, right?